# Azure Maps doesn't provide updated Canadian address

Tags: azure-maps

We find **Azure** Maps' data are pretty old. For the below addresses, **Bing/Google** Maps can show them, but Azure Maps Fuzzy search cannot recognize them:

```
1530 Shade Lane, Milton
2130 Wilson St, Innisfil
778 Alpenrose Ct, Windsor
1424 Helsinki Court, Windsor
```

Is there any chance to get an updated dataset?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to the product's support team, not this public Q&A forum, as discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Answer (score 0):

Bing and Azure Maps use the same data provider, so a bit surprised by your findings. Checking Bing Maps I found that the autocomplete seemed to recognize the addresses, but could not geocode them correctly. Often it returned city level results. Trying Azure Maps I found it returned the correct section of road, but not the exact house address.

Looking into the addresses you provide some of them are definitely look like newly constructed roads, so it's like that the Azure Maps data provider hasn't yet driven that road to capture the new data, or the data is still being processed.

In any case I'll pass this on to the data team to investigate. You can also report and track the status of data related issues here: https://feedback.azuremaps.com/

Comment: Thank you Ricky, our project has a pretty tight deadline we need adhere to. The solution uses Azure intensively, but unfortunately at this point of time, we have to switch Azure Map to Google Map plus Canada Post AddressComplete API (old fashion SOAP, which sucks). I will report this issue and another feedback to your team shortly.